# aframe hiro marker not working with nuxt.js

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, augmented-reality, aframe

i looked through the Ar.js Documentation(https://ar-js-org.github.io/AR.js-Docs/) and tried implementing the Marker Based Example on nuxt.js.

index.vue from my project

```
  <a-scene embedded arjs>
    <a-marker preset="hiro">
      <a-entity
        position="0 0 0"
        scale="0.05 0.05 0.05"
        gltf-model="https://arjs-cors-proxy.herokuapp.com/https://raw.githack.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/master/aframe/examples/image-tracking/nft/trex/scene.gltf"
      ></a-entity>
    </a-marker>
    <a-entity camera></a-entity>
  </a-scene>
</template>

<script>
//import Logo from '~/components/Logo.vue'

export default {
  components: {
    //Logo
  }
}
</script>
```

nuxt.js.config from my project. The important part for this question is where i modify vue.config and the head with.

```
export default {
  vue: {
    config: {
      productionTip: true,
      ignoredElements: [
        'a-scene',
        'a-entity',
        'a-camera',
        'a-animation',
        'a-sky',
        'a-marker'
      ]
    }
  },
  ssr: false,
  /*
   ** Headers of the page
   */
  head: {
    title: process.env.npm_package_name || '',
    script: [
      {
        src: 'https://aframe.io/releases/1.0.4/aframe.min.js'
      },
      {
        src:
          'https://raw.githack.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/master/aframe/build/aframe-ar.js'
      }
    ],
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      {
        hid: 'description',
        name: 'description',
        content: process.env.npm_package_description || ''
      }
    ],
    link: [{ rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }]
  },
  /*
   ** Customize the progress-bar color
   */
  loading: { color: '#fff' },
  /*
   ** Global CSS
   */
  css: [],
  /*
   ** Plugins to load before mounting the App
   */
  // plugins: ['~/plugins/aframe.js'],
  /*
   ** Nuxt.js dev-modules
   */
  buildModules: [
    // Doc: https://github.com/nuxt-community/eslint-module
    '@nuxtjs/eslint-module',
    // Doc: https://github.com/nuxt-community/nuxt-tailwindcss
    '@nuxtjs/tailwindcss'
  ],
  /*
   ** Nuxt.js modules
   */
  modules: [
    // Doc: https://axios.nuxtjs.org/usage
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxtjs/pwa'
  ],
  /*
   ** Axios module configuration
   ** See https://axios.nuxtjs.org/options
   */
  axios: {},
  /*
   ** Build configuration
   */
  build: {
    /*
     ** You can extend webpack config here
     */
    extend(config, ctx) {}
  }
}
```

Console from webapp

```
A-Frame Version: 1.0.4 (Date 2020-02-05, Commit #2b359246)
aframe.min.js:995 three Version (https://github.com/supermedium/three.js): ^0.111.6
aframe.min.js:995 WebVR Polyfill Version: ^0.10.10
webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js:8428 You are running Vue in development mode.
Make sure to turn on production mode when deploying for production.
See more tips at https://vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html
webpack-internal:///./node_modules/webpack-hot-middleware/client.js?reload=true&timeout=30000&ansiColors=&overlayStyles=&path=%2F__webpack_hmr%2Fclient&name=client:95 [HMR] connected
aframe-ar.js:3994 AR.js 3.3.1 - trackingBackend: artoolkit
aframe-ar.js:3528 ARjs.Anchor - changeMatrixMode: modelViewMatrix / markersAreaEnabled: false
aframe-ar.js:2023 THREEx.ArMarkerControls: 'markersAreaEnabled' is not a property of this material.
setParameters @ aframe-ar.js:2023
aframe-ar.js:2016 THREEx.ArMarkerControls: 'minConfidence' parameter is undefined.
setParameters @ aframe-ar.js:2016
aframe-ar.js:2 Allocated videoFrameSize 1228800
aframe-ar.js:2 Pattern detection mode set to 1.
aframe-ar.js:2 Pattern ratio size set to 0.500000.
```

My Problem: The nuxt.js app is working with the camera but it is not responding to the hiro marker or any custom marker and not showing the dinosaurier(here is a working example: https://ar-js-org.github.io/AR.js/aframe/examples/marker-based/basic.html with this marker https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/master/data/images/hiro.png).

Have a happy new year,

Philipp

Comment: Did you ever managed to solve this? I'm experiencing the same problem.